# Is it possible to add event listener in sprite using three.js

Tags: three.js

In my application, I wish to use sprite image on clicking this i need to move to next scene, i am able to achieve this by clicking on mesh and navigating to next scene, but it would be better if i use sprite to do further action in my application like moveTo functions etc. So, how to add event listener in sprite using three.js